# Named after - card puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, cards

[image: named after]

(this is a picture puzzle)

Hint is -'Named after'

Comment: Is it related to internet and domain names?

Comment: Something that goes like "To a missing black Jack, in search of unseen four Diamonds..."( based on the missing cards in each suit - namely: 2 Hearts, Ace & 3 Spades, 4 & 7 Diamonds, Jack of Clubs)

Comment: Not related to internet and domains.

Comment: Is it a single solution or does each stack represents a different solution..?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The person being named is...

> ...[François Édouard
>       Anatole Lucas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89douard_Lucas),...

...as the missing cards’...

> ...numerical values constitute the first 6
>  [Lucas numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number):
>   
>      
>   2           (♥),  
>   1         (ace ♠),  
>   3           (♠),  
>   4            (♦),  
>   7            (♦)   
>  11    (jack ♣),...

...which are named for the person being named.

Without knowing about this person’s name,
       you can still notice that...

> ...each two consecutive numbers add to the next number
>  (just as with
>   [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)).
>
> ```
>        2   1   3   4   7   11 . . .
>
>        2 + 1 = 3
>            1 + 3 = 4
>                3 + 4 = 7
>                    4 + 7 = 11
> ```

You might even notice a way to make increasingly large leaps,...

> ```
>        2  1  3     4     7  11  18  29  47  76 . . . 843  1364  2207 . . .
>
>              3 x 3 - 2 = 7
>                          7 x 7   -  2 = 47
>                                         47 x 47         -   2 = 2207
> ```
>
> ...a feature not shared by Fibonacci numbers.